Changes in IntelliJ Community Edition project not reflecting in terminal output
I'm working on a simple Java project using IntelliJ Community Edition. I created a simple project with build system in IntelliJ and I've encountered a problem with updating the output in the terminal.
Initially, when I add a System.out.println() statement to my main class, the output is correctly displayed in the terminal. However, subsequent additions of multiple System.out.println() statements do not update the terminal; it still shows the old content. Each time, I need to rebuild the project to see any new changes, which is quite cumbersome.
This issue occurs both on Windows and on WSL. I have Java 17 installed on WSL and Java 21 on Windows. In the project structure, the SDK is correctly configured.
Interestingly, when I open the same project in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition, everything works as expected, and the terminal reflects changes immediately.
Is there something I might be doing wrong, or is there a specific configuration or setting in IntelliJ Community Edition that I need to adjust? I'm relatively new to Java and would appreciate any guidance on this matter.

After making changes to the source files you should compile them manually by pressing .

It's a known issue and it will be fixed in 2024.2 release: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-341365

I found what the problem was. If we create a new project in IntelliJ Community, the path of the project within WSL is \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\. However, if I create a new project using \\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\, then everything compiles with every change I make.
IntelliJ Community seems to has some problem with wsl.localhost.
